# What will apache issue for $SERVER_NAME and $SERVER_PORT when server is behind a VIP/LoadBalancer?

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing

What will apache issue for $SERVER_NAME and $SERVER_PORT when server is behind a VIP/LoadBalancer?

I believe we will be using F5 with LTM

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are using [Source Address Translation](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_snat.html) or not. If you use this feature, it will show the BIG-IP's self-IP. Otherwise it will show the origional source address.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the F5 is doing something specific to change those (and it can) it should work just like it would if the F5 were not there. The F5 load balancer can translate ports and even server names if you let it, but you have to tell it to do that.